# Log odds understanding

Tags: logistic-regression, correlation, logarithmic

**Here is my understanding of one reason why we prefer log odds over odds & probability. Please let me know if I got it right.**

Reasons why we choose log-odds-

The range of probability values: $[0,1]$,
The range of odds values: $[0,\infty]$,
The range of log-odds values: $[-\infty,+\infty]$

Probability & odds lie in a restricted range, while log-odds doesn't. When values lie in a restricted range, the correlation between variables falls.

Following is an example where correlation between 'Hours spent studying' & 'Test score' reduced after the range was restricted.

[image]

Comment: There are some advantages of using log_odds. (log scale; additivity of log_ods) but i don't understandhow it would be linked to the second part of the question.

Comment: This article talks about restricted range & correlation: https://www.statisticshowto.com/restricted-range/                                                             
If not this, may I know what the issue with a restricted range of values is (in logistic regression)?